# Data binding in fetched v-html content

Tags: vue.js

I'm fetching a string template (not a Vue template, simple string that has html attributes) from our server which looks like `Hi {{ name }} (...)` and putting it into:

```
data: {
  return: {
    template: '', // after template is fetched it goes here
    name: 'John'
  }
}
```

but instead of `Hi John` I get `Hi {{ name }}`. Not sure how to solve it - any easy solutions to that?

Comment: do you have the [vue-compiler](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only) included?

Comment: yes, I use webpack - I never really used `render()` function

Comment: webpack is build only, if you fetch "templates" at runtime you will need the compiler at runtime; you can omit the compiler if you build your template programmaticly (`h()`) but since you explicitly mention `{{}}` I assume you want to compile the templates via the compiler at runtime which means - not at webpack time

Comment: I misexplained. By template in this case I mean html string that I get from server (the same one as in example) and that string is parsed via `v-html`. The problem is that mustache interpolations are not binded, they are just parsed as they are.

Comment: exactly, to "compile" the moustaches you need [Vue.compile](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) somewhere after you fetch the template. With the caveat: `Compiles a template string into a render function. Only available in the full build.` - hence I was asking if you have the compiler loaded at all.

Comment: maybe I helps if i explain it this way: After webpack there are no templates, only render functions (webpack/vue-cli precompiles them). Now you want to dynamically add a render function from a (server-side-fetched) template at runtime. Either you compile it using the vue-compiler or some other means of turning the string into a function.

Comment: Okay, so from what I understood - I'm just using runtime-only build and full-build is when I can also compile on client side. Am I correct? If so - is that one https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the template strings are not Vue templates then you could parse the `{{ ... }}` placeholders yourself using a RegExp.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Smith',
      title: 'Mr',
      template: 'Hi {{ title }} {{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}'
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    templateOutput () {
      return this.template.replace(/{{\s*([\S]+?)\s*}}/g, (full, property) => {
        return escape(this[property])
      })
      
      function escape (str) {
        if (str == null) {
          return ''
        }
        
        return String(str)
          .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
          .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
          .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
          .replace(/"/g, '&#34;')
          .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-html="templateOutput"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What `escape()` function is for?

Comment: @jeand'arme It ensures that those special characters will be treated literally, as plain text, rather than interpreting them as HTML. This ensures both correctness and provides protection from XSS injection. You will need to take care to ensure that the templates themselves are similarly safe from that perspective. If your templates don't contain any HTML then you'd be better off avoiding `v-html` altogether, in which case the escaping would no longer be required.

Comment: Nice! I actually only fetch html template from server, but send only plain data back because template is a transactional email template. Thanks for explanation and solution!